# How to set umlaut ( german character ü ) as mnemonic for JComboBox

Tags: java, swing

I have used the following code:

```
JComboBox cb=new JComboBox();
JLabel label = new JLabel("für");
label.setDisplayedMnemonic('ü');
label.setLabelFor(cb);
```

This code does not work. However if I set the mnemonic to 'f' instead of 'ü' it works fine.
There is an API in jdk7 that allows this but I could not find any such API in jdk 6:
JDK 7 api :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getExtendedKeyCodeForChar%28int%29

Comment: What if you use `setDisplayedMnemonicIndex` instead?

Comment: using the index doesn't help - the problem is the key mapping in the ui-delegate (which doesn't work)

Answer (score 3):

The DisplayedMnemonic is ok. the 'ü' is underlined , but:
This will `installKeyboardActions()` ine `BasicLabelUI` for the inputMap of your JLabel with the KeyStroke: `alt pressed UNKNOWN`, which will definitely not work.